# Creating a [string : Class] dictionary in Swift 4

Tags: swift, class, generics, reflection, types

I've been looking around for a way to store in a swift dictionary, a string as its key and the Class as the value

Basically, I want to store:
[
  "view" : UIView.self,
  "segment" : UISegmentedControl
]

this is so i can parse a json and compare against a parameter against the class held in the dictionary, like so:

```
func checkObject<T>(_ object : T, forKey key : String) -> Bool {
   if let d = dictionary_of_string_classes[key], d.self == T.self {
     return true
   }

   return false
}
```

however, the implementation of the solution is escaping me after 2 days

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you use the Any type in a dictionary? Like: Dictionary<String, Any>()

Comment: I can't think of a reason why I would want to do this really? but basically you can either use an AnyObject type, a common.. parent class, or a protocol shared between all elements (the swiftier way)  to do something like this. you just need to determine what groups these elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about this solution?

```
var dictionary_of_string_classes: [String: Any.Type] = [:]
dictionary_of_string_classes["1"] = String.self
dictionary_of_string_classes["2"] = URL.self

func checkObject<T: Any>(_ object : T.Type, forKey key : String) -> Bool {
    return dictionary_of_string_classes[key] == object.self
}

print(checkObject(String.self, forKey: "1")) // true
print(checkObject(String.self, forKey: "2")) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
var dictionary_of_string_classes: [String: NSObject.Type] = [:]
dictionary_of_string_classes["hello"] = UITableView.self

func checkObject<T>(_ object : T, forKey key : String) -> Bool {

    if let d = dictionary_of_string_classes[key], d.self is T {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

checkObject(UICollectionView.self, forKey: "hello") //false
checkObject(UITableView.self, forKey: "hello") //true
```

Comment: close but not quite, need to store unrelated classes i do not own (i have already have a similar solution to yours). Imagine trying to store ANY Foundation or UIKit or MapKit class there

Comment: What about NSObject class? something like  dictionary_of_string_classes: [String: NSObject.Type] = [:]

Comment: thanks again for the input, but it should also be able to handle POSO objects, the capability is to be build in a Framework and any client code should be able to register any class they want (including their own plain swift class)